# excel string comparison is failing when it should not

Tags: excel

When I do `=RIGHT(DATA!$A$2:$A$1501,1)` I get the value 3. When I do `=$B$5` I get the value 3. When I do `=RIGHT(DATA!$A$2:$A$1501,1)=$B$5` I get the value FALSE.

How the f%^k can 3 not equal 3. Is this a data type issue? Do I need a cast? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's probably a data type issue. Try

```
=RIGHT(DATA!$A$2:$A$1501,1)=TEXT($B$5,"general")
```

via: [The JLD Excel Blog - String to number, Number to String](http://jldexcel.blogspot.com/2006/01/string-to-number-number-to-string.html)

Comment: argh! The hideous syntax! It hurts!

Comment: The goggles! They do nothing! ;-) I've seen much worse. I've seen IFs nested 30 levels deep (and attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion, too).

Answer (score 0):

One of your "3"s is probably text.  Try this:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(DATA!$A$2:$A$1501,1))=VALUE($B$5)
```