# Excel String Comparison Failing

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Checking `=D2`, I get `Aransas`.  When I try and assign another cell with `=D2="Aransas"` it spits out `False`.  When I assign `C5` as `=D2`, type `Aransas` in `C6`, and try `=C5=C6` it returns `True`.  However, `C5="Aransas"` still gives me `False`.

What the frickity frack is going on?  Is it the formatting of the cells or the way I'm typing strings?  I already checked here: [excel string comparison is failing when it should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243305/excel-string-comparison-is-failing-when-it-should-not) , but I can't see how it could be a type issue, seeing as it's literally just comparing two strings.

Comment: Is there a white space/line break in the value in D2?

Comment: I checked, no whitespace, no line breaks.  I suspect it has something to do with the formatting of the cell, because when I copy-pasted the cell, cleared it, then tried `D2="Aransas"` again, it worked.  Checking the formatting of the cell, both are "General".

I want to avoid doing this for the entire document because there's already a lot of data in it and I really don't want to have to go through and reproduce every single cell that needs this (there are around 500).

Comment: Hm, I don't think it should have to do with the format.  I put "Aransas" in D2, and in F2 put `="Aransas"=D2` and I get `TRUE`.  Then, changing D2 to Currency, Accounting, Short Date, etc. doesn't affect the outcome, it stays `TRUE`.  I suspect perhaps it was some white space, or other kind of thing, in the cell?  Did you try `="Aransas"=Trim(d2)`, perhaps that might help.

Comment: Still no, though when I change the value to `'Aransas` in the cell, it returns `TRUE`.  I'm not too familiar with Excel's representation of strings--is there any way one could get something that appears as a string but isn't recognized as one in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED: For some reason, what seemed to be very obviously text (e.g. "Aransas") wasn't being treated as such.  With Excel, things that are usually autoformatted like numbers or dates can be kept from converting if one puts an apostrophe `'` in front of the desired text.  What I ended up doing was changing all the relevant cells to Text format, and *voilà*, the equality comparison returns as it should.